# storing *Key to GAE local datastore give me error in DataStoreViewer

Tags: google-app-engine, go, google-cloud-datastore

I have a *Key in entity A referring entity B.
I can put() the data to data store without error but when try to browse entity A from Datastore Viewer, it gives the following error:

> 'Incomplete key found for reference property %s.' % name) 
>   BadValueError: Incomplete key found for reference property ds_key.

it seems blaming the key to be incomplete. If I use NewKey() to acquire a complete key, I need to manually provide a unique string or int ID to the key which is not what I want. I just want datastore generate a key of B for me and I keep that key from entity A.

thanks

Comment: I tried Encode() + DecodeKey() to save the key as string but it doesn't work.

"datastore: internal error: server returned the wrong number of entities"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Put()`](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/go/datastore/reference#Put) returns a complete Key even when you `Put()` with an incomplete Key.  You need to

1. Generate an incomplete Key for `B` (no need to manually provide a unique ID).
2. `Put()` `B` to the datastore and look at the return value so you have a complete Key for it.
3. Use that value in entity `A`.
4. `Put()` `A` to the datastore.

Now `A` will correctly reference `B`.